# Initializing Template Driven Form in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I'm looking to initialize certain form fields on a form and then call a function that has a `if(this.form.valid)` condition on it.

on the `ngOnInit` function I have an API call that gets some basic info and fills it on the form:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.getInfo(this.user.id).subscribe(
        userInfo => {
            this.formModel.fieldA = userInfo.A; 
            this.formModel.fieldB = userInfo.B; 
            this.formModel.fieldC = userInfo.C; 
            this.doStuff();
        }
    );
}
```

However when calling `this.doStuff()` the form is invalid, even though there are no errors and clicking on the submit button seems to force the validation and causes it to be valid.

Is there a way I can manually trigger the form's validation so that `valid` becomes true?

Edit: [Stackblitz](https://angular-yfzzzr.stackblitz.io).

Comment: `this.form.updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: @joyBlanks I'm getting a "Property 'updateValueAndValidity' does not exist on type 'NgForm'".

Comment: can you put up a small stackblitz with some dummy data use of({}).subscribe to simulate the apiservice

Comment: how does your template look like?

Comment: I've added a Stackblitzwith dummy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular template-driven forms are in fact asynchronous. This is more prominently shown when working with the `NgForm` directive in component, compared to reactive forms. If you were to put a `debugger` in your `calc()` function from the **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkta19?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**:

You would see that in the `calc` function when called from `OnInit` shows that the form is not valid, nor does the form controls have any value:

[image]

So your `if` in `calc()`:

```ts
if (this.formExample && this.formExample.valid)
```

is not `truthy` and `result` will not be computed since the form is not `valid`.

So if we wait a tick before calling `calc()` that should solve your issue:

```ts
this.getInfo().subscribe(
  info => {
    this.params.field1 = info.field1;
    this.params.field2 = info.field2;
    // wait a tick!
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.calc();
    })
  }
);
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kx8iu5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**